# Headers Issue in one Section

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, double-sided, books

I am relatively new in Latex. I am facing problems in headers. 
In my document, the headers works fine for 'Table of Contents', 'List of figures', 'list of tables' section but in 'Acronyms' section I see header as **list of tables** (the header of previous section). 
After it, the headers are working fine in the chapters.
How to get rid of that.

I am including a minimum working sample with only table of contents and abbreviations and this problem can be seen. In minimum working sample the header of accronyms is contents.

Document Class: two side book

MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small \slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small \slshape \rightmark}
\def\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\def\footrulewidth{0 pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{List of Acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[SEPSEPSEP]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.3\parsep}

%A    
    \acro{ack}[ACK]{acknowledgement}
    \acro{ann}[ANN]{Arificial Neural Network}
    \acro{ap}[AP]{Access Point}   
    \acro{aqm}[AQM]{Active Queue Management}
    \acro{arp}[ARP]{Address Resolution Protocol}
    \acro{auc}[AUC]{Area under the ROC curve}

%B  
    \acro{ber}[BER]{Bit Error Rate}

%C  
    \acro{cbr}[CBR]{Constant Bit Rate}
    \acro{cdn}[CDN]{Content Distribution Networks}
    \acro{ci}[CI]{Confidence Interval}
    \acro{codec}[CODEC]{Coder-Decoder}  
    \acro{cpu}[CPU]{Central Processing Unit} 
    \acro{cv}[CV]{Cross Validation}
    \acro{cts}[CTS]{Clear to Send}

%D  
    \acro{dash}[DASH]{Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP}
    \acro{dfwmac}[DFWMAC]{distributed foundation wireless MAC}

%E  
    \acro{edca}[EDCA]{Enhanced Distributed Channel Access}
    \acro{eit}[EIT]{Elektro och Informationsteknik}

%F      
    \acro{fec}[FEC]{Forward Error Correction}
    \acro{fifo}[FIFO]{First In First Out} 
    \acro{ftp}[FTP]{File Transfer Protocol}  
%G

%H  
    \acro{hd}[HD]{High Definition}
    \acro{hp}[HP]{Hewlett-Packard}    
    \acro{http}[HTTP]{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
%I    
    \acro{ieee}[IEEE]{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}
    \acro{ietf}[IETF]{Internet Engineering Task Force}
    \acro{ip}[IP]{Internet Protocol}
    \acro{ipdv}[IPDV]{Inter Packet Delay Variance}
    \acro{ippm}[IPPM]{IP Performance metric}
    \acro{isp}[ISP]{Internet Service Provider}
    \acro{isps}[ISPs]{Internet Service Providers}
    \acro{itu}[ITU]{International Telecommunication Union}
    \acro{itut}[ITU-T]{International Telecommunication Union - Telecommunication Standardization Sector}

%R
    \acro{rbfn}[RBFN]{Radial Basis Function Networks}   
    \acro{ram}[RAM]{Random Access Memory}
    \acro{rat}[RAT]{Radio Access Technology}
    \acro{rbf}[RBF]{Radial Basis Function}
    \acro{rfc}[RFC]{Request for Comments}
    \acro{rfe}[RFE]{Recursive Feature Elimination}
    \acro{roc}[ROC]{Receiver Operating Characteristic}
    \acro{rssi}[RSSI]{Recieved Signal Strength Indicator}
    \acro{rto}[RTOs]{Retransmission Time Outs}
    \acro{rts}[RTS]{Request to Send}
    \acro{rtt}[RTT]{Round Trip Time}

%S  
    \acro{sla}[SLA]{Service Level Agreement}
    \acro{snr}[SNR]{Signal to Noise Ratio}
    \acro{ssim}[SSIM]{Structural Similarity}
    \acro{svc}[SVC]{Support Vector Classification}
    \acro{svm}[SVM]{Support Vector Machine}

%T      
    \acro{tcp}[TCP]{Transmission Control Protocol}
    \acro{tv}[TV]{Television}
    \acro{twamp}[TWAMP]{Two-Way Active Measurement Protocol}

%U  
    \acro{udp}[UDP]{User Datagram Protocol}
    \acro{ue}[UE]{User Equipment}
    \acro{umts}[UMTS]{Universal Mobile Telecommunications Services}
    \acro{url}[URL]{Uniform Resource Locator}

%V  
    \acro{vod}[VOD]{Video on Demand}
    \acro{voip}[VOIP]{Voice over Internet Protocol}
    \acro{vqm}[VQM]{Video Quality Metric}

%W     
    \acro{wifi}[Wi-Fi]{Wireless Fidelity}
    \acro{wlan}[WLAN]{Wireless LAN}

%X
%Y
%Z
 \end{acronym}

\chapter{Test}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{wifi} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{wlan} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{vqm} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{voip} blah blah blah \ac{vod} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{url} blah blah blah \ac{umts} blah blah blah \ac{tv} blah blah blah  \ac{ue} blah blah blah \ac{udp} blah blah blah \ac{twamp} blah blah blah \ac{tcp} blah blah blah \ac{svm} blah blah blah \ac{svc} blah blah blah \ac{ssim} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{snr} blah blah blah \ac{sla} blah blah blah \ac{rtt} blah blah blah \ac{rts} blah blah blah \ac{rto} blah blah blah \ac{rssi} blah blah blah {roc} blah blah blah \ac{ann} blah blah blah \ac{ap} blah blah blah \ac{ber} blah blah blah \ac{cbr} blah blah blah \ac{cdn} blah blah blah \ac{cpu} blah blah blah \ac{dash} blah blah blah \ac{eit} blah blah blah \ac{ftp} blah blah blah \ac{hd} blah blah blah \ac{http} blah blah blah \ac{ieee} blah blah blah \ac{ietf} blah blah blah \ac{ip} blah blah blah \ac{ipdv} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{isp} blah blah blah \ac{isps} blah blah blah \ac{itu}

 \end{document}
```

The images of pdf generated can be seen as follows and the error can be seen at image 3, where the header is Contents although it should be 'List of Accronyms' while at image 2 the Header is correct i.e Contents
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which shows your problem. At them moment it is impossible to see what happens in the TeX-code of your "Acronyms" section.

Comment: My impression is that this list of acronyms is started with `\chapter*`; since you seem to have it in `\frontmatter`, just use `\chapter`.

Comment: @Christian, Thanks, I have included a minimum working sample

Comment: @egreg, That have seemed to work, now the header is fine, if i put \chapter, but then list of acronyms is labeled as chapter 1. I want that to be just list of acronyms

Comment: Are you using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`? If not, do. In your  original picture you had Roman page numbers; if you did it with `\pagenumbering{roman}`, then it was wrong.

Comment: You could manually set it using `\markboth{}{}`, where the first argument would be what you see, called `\leftmark`, and the other one, `\rightmark`. The latter would be set by sectionnames.

Comment: @egreg, I just used \frontmatter and \mainmatter after seeing u first comment. After using them, the header becomes 'Chapter 0 List of Acronyms' How to just make List of Acronyms

Comment: @Umar I modified the code to make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, but you also need some adjustment because you're using `fancyhdr` that has the bad habit of redefining `\chaptermark`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small \slshape \rightmark}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\let\standardchaptermark\chaptermark
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\chaptermark\standardchaptermark

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{List of Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[SEPSEPSEP]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.3\parsep}

%A    
    \acro{ack}[ACK]{acknowledgement}
    \acro{ann}[ANN]{Arificial Neural Network}
    \acro{ap}[AP]{Access Point}   
    \acro{aqm}[AQM]{Active Queue Management}
    \acro{arp}[ARP]{Address Resolution Protocol}
    \acro{auc}[AUC]{Area under the ROC curve}

%B  
    \acro{ber}[BER]{Bit Error Rate}

%C  
    \acro{cbr}[CBR]{Constant Bit Rate}
    \acro{cdn}[CDN]{Content Distribution Networks}
    \acro{ci}[CI]{Confidence Interval}
    \acro{codec}[CODEC]{Coder-Decoder}  
    \acro{cpu}[CPU]{Central Processing Unit} 
    \acro{cv}[CV]{Cross Validation}
    \acro{cts}[CTS]{Clear to Send}

%D  
    \acro{dash}[DASH]{Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP}
    \acro{dfwmac}[DFWMAC]{distributed foundation wireless MAC}

%E  
    \acro{edca}[EDCA]{Enhanced Distributed Channel Access}
    \acro{eit}[EIT]{Elektro och Informationsteknik}

%F      
    \acro{fec}[FEC]{Forward Error Correction}
    \acro{fifo}[FIFO]{First In First Out} 
    \acro{ftp}[FTP]{File Transfer Protocol}  
%G

%H  
    \acro{hd}[HD]{High Definition}
    \acro{hp}[HP]{Hewlett-Packard}    
    \acro{http}[HTTP]{Hypertext Transfer Protocol}
%I    
    \acro{ieee}[IEEE]{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}
    \acro{ietf}[IETF]{Internet Engineering Task Force}
    \acro{ip}[IP]{Internet Protocol}
    \acro{ipdv}[IPDV]{Inter Packet Delay Variance}
    \acro{ippm}[IPPM]{IP Performance metric}
    \acro{isp}[ISP]{Internet Service Provider}
    \acro{isps}[ISPs]{Internet Service Providers}
    \acro{itu}[ITU]{International Telecommunication Union}
    \acro{itut}[ITU-T]{International Telecommunication Union - Telecommunication Standardization Sector}

%R
    \acro{rbfn}[RBFN]{Radial Basis Function Networks}   
    \acro{ram}[RAM]{Random Access Memory}
    \acro{rat}[RAT]{Radio Access Technology}
    \acro{rbf}[RBF]{Radial Basis Function}
    \acro{rfc}[RFC]{Request for Comments}
    \acro{rfe}[RFE]{Recursive Feature Elimination}
    \acro{roc}[ROC]{Receiver Operating Characteristic}
    \acro{rssi}[RSSI]{Recieved Signal Strength Indicator}
    \acro{rto}[RTOs]{Retransmission Time Outs}
    \acro{rts}[RTS]{Request to Send}
    \acro{rtt}[RTT]{Round Trip Time}

%S  
    \acro{sla}[SLA]{Service Level Agreement}
    \acro{snr}[SNR]{Signal to Noise Ratio}
    \acro{ssim}[SSIM]{Structural Similarity}
    \acro{svc}[SVC]{Support Vector Classification}
    \acro{svm}[SVM]{Support Vector Machine}

%T      
    \acro{tcp}[TCP]{Transmission Control Protocol}
    \acro{tv}[TV]{Television}
    \acro{twamp}[TWAMP]{Two-Way Active Measurement Protocol}

%U  
    \acro{udp}[UDP]{User Datagram Protocol}
    \acro{ue}[UE]{User Equipment}
    \acro{umts}[UMTS]{Universal Mobile Telecommunications Services}
    \acro{url}[URL]{Uniform Resource Locator}

%V  
    \acro{vod}[VOD]{Video on Demand}
    \acro{voip}[VOIP]{Voice over Internet Protocol}
    \acro{vqm}[VQM]{Video Quality Metric}

%W     
    \acro{wifi}[Wi-Fi]{Wireless Fidelity}
    \acro{wlan}[WLAN]{Wireless LAN}

%X
%Y
%Z
 \end{acronym}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\ac{wifi} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{wlan} blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{vqm} 
blah blah blah blah blah blah \ac{voip} blah blah blah \ac{vod} blah blah blah blah blah 
blah \ac{url} blah blah blah \ac{umts} blah blah blah \ac{tv} blah blah blah \ac{ue} blah 
blah blah \ac{udp} blah blah blah \ac{twamp} blah blah blah \ac{tcp} blah blah blah 
\ac{svm} blah blah blah \ac{svc} blah blah blah \ac{ssim} blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\ac{snr} blah blah blah \ac{sla} blah blah blah \ac{rtt} blah blah blah \ac{rts} blah blah 
blah \ac{rto} blah blah blah \ac{rssi} blah blah blah {roc} blah blah blah \ac{ann} blah 
blah blah \ac{ap} blah blah blah \ac{ber} blah blah blah \ac{cbr} blah blah blah \ac{cdn} 
blah blah blah \ac{cpu} blah blah blah \ac{dash} blah blah blah \ac{eit} blah blah blah 
\ac{ftp} blah blah blah \ac{hd} blah blah blah \ac{http} blah blah blah \ac{ieee} blah 
blah blah \ac{ietf} blah blah blah \ac{ip} blah blah blah \ac{ipdv} blah blah blah blah 
blah blah \ac{isp} blah blah blah \ac{isps} blah blah blah \ac{itu}

% populate the toc
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}
\chapter{A}\section{B}\section{C}\section{D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to put headers in small letters (not capital letters) in \mainmatter. But its not working. I was adding \if. Whats the error here `\if@mainmatter`
`\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1] \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}`
`\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}`
`\fi`

Comment: @Umar `\fancyhead[RE]{\small\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}` and similarly for `\rightmark`.

Comment: where should i add this code ?

Comment: I want to keep LIST OF ACRONYMS but then Chapter1. Abcedf... (something like that)

Comment: @Umar That code should replace the similar one you have. I'm not sure what would be the reason for having something all uppercase and something not.

Comment: Its working fine, after I updated it all was small so thats ok, Thanks